# having X axis in special discrete values

Tags: matlab

i want to plot Y versus the corresponding values in X in MATLAB,and i want to see the points (x,y) just when x=5,10,2000.because these values are really far apart the graph is not good.what must be done with my X axis?

thank u.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you might have tried or what bad output you're getting. I'd suggest expanding your post more by editing it to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the 5,10,2000 values plotted, then maybe do:

```
plot(X([5,10,2000]),Y([5,10,2000]),'o')
```

or else you can try plotting the whole thing, but represent the X-axis as log:

```
semilogx(X,Y)
```

HTH!